# AppDelegate instantiated last on launch

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data, appdelegate

I'm very comfortable with writing iOS apps, but OS X unexpectedly seems somewhat alien.

Here's the question upfront (read on for context):

When my application launches using the .xib set in the Main Interface field under the deployment info of my apps target, **why does the AppDelegate get instantiated after the ViewControllers?**

**Context** (no pun intended):

The reason I ask is because I'm using Core Data (spare me any heckling for this decision), and typically you keep a pointer to the MOC (Managed Object Context) in AppDelegate. One of my controllers is trying to get this MOC instance variable but the AppDelegate instance isn't around yet and therefore my app doesn't present data just after launch.

The AppDelegate and the two ViewControllers are in the .xib. The VCs are hooked to views inside a split view. They're trying to use the MOC in viewDidLoad to make queries. They are accessing the AppDelegate like this:

```
let delegate = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
let moc = delegate.managedObjectContext
```

This will crash as the `.delegate` property of the `sharedApplication()` returns nil.

I tried making an NSWindowController from the .xib in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and removing the .xib from the Main Interface field, but then `applicationDidFinishLaunching` doesn't get called at all.

I've ensured that all the connections in IB for from the Application and the Files Owner (NSApplcation) delegate IBOutlets to the AppDelegate have been made.

**UPDATE** - 31/03/15

Stephen Darlington's answer below offers a good solution for my/this case. And as I understand it's actually better to setup the MOC in the way he's suggested.

If a correct answer arrives that explains why the AppDelegate is being instantiated at some later time in the launch process, I'll mark it correct instead of Stephen's. Thanks Stephen!

Comment: Where or how are you creating the instances of the ViewControllers? Do the view controller instances also reside inside the Main nib file? When you say "One of my controllers is trying to get this MOC instance variable but the AppDelegate instance isn't around yet”, does this view controller have an `IBOutlet` to the `AppDelegate`, and/or in what method of the view controller are you trying to access the `AppDelegate` (for example, `init`, `awakeFromNib`, etc.)?

Comment: Thanks for pointing valuable missing information @NSGod. I've edited my question to answer your questions.

Comment: Try `@NSApplicationMain` in the AppDelegate class to try forcing it to init the delegate instance sooner?

Comment: @stevesliva that's been placed at the top of AppDelegate, outside the class definition by the Xcode template. Is that correct? If so, the problem is still occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "easy" solution would be to have `managedObjectContext` create a MOC if one doesn't exist (i.e., change it from a property to a method). That way which ever code gets there first the stack will be available.

(I'll spare the lectures about both creating the Core Data stack in the app delegate and accessing the app delegate like that!)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! That's what I was moving towards. Where would you recommend I hold the pointer to the MOC? I'd of course have to make it a static on some class? Dare I even say AppDel...... p.s. thanks for sparing me 

Comment: Most recently I've used [SLCoreDataStack](https://github.com/OliverLetterer/SLCoreDataStack) successfully. But even if you don't like that, the idea of keeping the stack in a separate class is a good one.

Comment: That's great, thanks again! I'm torn as to whether to mark your answer as correct as it doesn't actually solve my questions but does offer an alternative solution that works for me. I'm thinking in respect to other people looking for why AppDel is instantiated at some later time..

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option *without* having to subclass NSApplication:

- Don't put your view controllers in the .xib that you set as the Main Interface, just have the Main Menu (menu bar), AppDelegate and Font Manager in there.
- Then make your view controllers in other .xibs.
- Then in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method init your view controllers from their .xib files.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue with setting up [Parse](http://parse.com). To get around it, I simply subclassed NSApplication and set it as the `Principle class` in the `Info.plist`. In your NSApplication subclass, override the init methods and initialise Parse or anything else you need to, there.